# CSS @media print with inches gives other sizes after printing

Tags: html, css, reactjs, printing, media-queries

I'm making a project where I have to print a single div of my page. The problem is that the `@page` tag does not affect anything when I try to print the content. Also, I decided to simply put to the element the real world dimentions that I want to print, but the sizes of the printed content does not match the specified ones.

My css code is:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        width: 3.5in;
        height: 2in;
    }
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #ticket, #ticket * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #ticket {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #ff0000;
        border: 1px solid yellowgreen;
        width: 3.5in;
        height: 2in;
    }
}
```

I've tried things like `@page { size: A3 }` and a lot of stuff but It does not work.
Basically I need to be able to print something with real world sizes, and when I click on print, the print configuration handle the stylesheet correctly,
I don't know if that is possible or if there is a simple way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

THE @PAGE RULE
The @page rule lets you specify various aspects of a page box. For example, you will want to specify the dimensions of your pages. The rule below specifies a default page size of 5.5 by 8.5 inches. If you intend to print a book, perhaps by a print-on-demand service, then finding out the sizes you can use is important.

@page { size: 5.5in 8.5in;} //try to apply height width like this

Comment: When I do that I'm still watching the same when I click on print. It sets me a default of letter. Even If I reduce a lot the page size nothings changes.

Comment: can u share html as well ?
it will give a better overview of the problem

Comment: The code is really simple. Is a react component, By now I'm just testing with this: `<div id="ticket">Just print this</div>`

Answer (score 1):

I am not pretty sure what is your pointing in your post but I have a feeling that this might help.

Create a CSS stylesheet or simply add **style tag** in your HTML header.

```
    <style>
        @media print {
           @page {
                  size: 5.5in 8.5in ;
                  size: landscape;
                 }
             }
     </style>
```

By this, paper size and layout selection will be disabled in your window print. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to print a business card from my HTML. When I sent the page to the printer, and I measure the results, the sizes of the content is not accurate.